# Why was this question deleted? Could it be Un-deleted?

Tags: discussion, deletion, deleted-questions

https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/26888/was-joesph-smith-a-prophet

That's my question.  Originally it was off-topic, but I edited it, and I think it should be undeleted.  Is that possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I deleted it because it's not possible to save it via an edit: it must be rewritten. Also, it's been closed by another moderator and received no reopen votes. We normally cycle and clean off closed questions where there is no activity from the home page.

The question can't be saved because we decided not to debate religious topics on this site: being a religious "prophet" is clearly something which implies divinity. Also - your definition of prophet ("one whose all their prophecies come true") is problematic, because it's arbitrary, too wide and because it assumes prophecies are necessarily true or false (whereas, mostly, they are going to be undecided).

If we allowed questions like yours, then we would also need to allow equivalent questions such as "does reincarnation exits?" or "was Jesus the son of God?". We don't do that for a reason.

Comment: That makes sense.  Would it then be on topic, if I rewrote it as more "did what he say come true"?

Comment: @cullub you'd have to choose one specific claim: two things that can be separately true or false make two separate questions.

Comment: I see - thank you!

Comment: Also, could you put a link in your question for "we decided not to debate religious topics" - I'm interested to learn more.

Comment: http://meta.skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/621/politics-beliefs-and-motivations-questions-should-not-be-allowed-here

Comment: @cullub More specifically, [Are religious questions on-topic?](http://meta.skeptics.stackexchange.com/q/63/2703) is about "is religion true?" (conversely [Politics, beliefs and motivations questions should not be allowed here](http://meta.skeptics.stackexchange.com/q/621/2703) is about "is person X religious?").